# Using applescript I want to move every file within the folder to the root folder

Tags: applescript

I have been trying to make a script to move every file within a folder to the root folder to include every sub folder. I don't want to make a new folder just move it to the root folder.

I want to be able to select the folder and then the action be completed on that specific folder only.

The reason is for organization, my exact situation is I have over a TB of movies and there's files within folders within folders. I want all those files on the root folder so that I can organize them how I deem fit. Also I would like to copy and delete instead of move as research has led me to believe is the best route.

Well I couldn't get the script to work but i did find a link to a workflow that does exactly what I'm looking for:

http://www.macworld.com/article/1160660/automator_filesfromsubfolders.html

---

***I updated above keeping this section for history purposes, everything in between this dotted lines is what I would have deleted after editing***

I have tried to reverse engineer this script below, that i found but, I just can't get it to work like I want to. Any and all help will be much apprieciated, I am very new to scripting and I have come to a rock.

2nd Attempt
tell application "finder"
        set main_folder to (choose folder with prompt "choose the main folder")
        set sub_folders to folders of main_folder
        repeat with each_folder in sub_folders
        move (every file of each_folder) to main_folder with replacing
        end repeat
        try
        end try
        end tell

1st Attempt
tell application "Finder"
set sourceFolder to folder "MOVE ME" -- of disk "blah", etc.
 my moveFilesFrom(sourceFolder)
 end tell

on moveFilesFrom(thisFolder)
tell application "Finder"
set filesToMove to every file of thisFolder
repeat with aFIle in filesToMove
 move aFIle to folder destFolder
end repeat
set subFolders to (every folder of thisFolder)
repeat with aFolder in subFolders
my moveFilesFrom(aFolder)
end repeat
end tell
end moveFilesFrom

**The finder times out when I use it on a a folder containing a lot of information and sub-folders, I used it on a test folder yesterday and it worked with no problem but substantially smaller.**

I am now using this script provided by adayzdone

```
    set myFolder to (choose folder with prompt "choose the main folder")
    tell application "Finder"
    set myfiles to get every item of (entire contents of folder myFolder) whose kind ≠ "Folder"
    move myfiles to myFolder
    end tell
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
set myFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "testFolder"
tell application "Finder"
    set myFiles to get every item of (entire contents of folder myFolder) whose kind ≠ "Folder"
    move myFiles to myFolder
end tell
```

or you can use a shell script like Lri suggested:

```
set myFolder to quoted form of (choose folder with prompt "choose the main folder")'s POSIX path
do shell script "cd " & myFolder & "; find . -type f -exec mv {} " & myFolder & " \\;"
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to copy and then delete just to be sure I don't lose my files due to stalling, power, etc. What should I add for that?

Comment: I can't think of a scenario that would make you lose files by using the script above. The worst case scenario would be that they remain in their subfolders, in which case you could simply run the script again.

Comment: The edited version has altered my laptop. What I assumed it did was move files outside of the specific folder chosen. Almost like it moved my preferences and other things and now the computer doesn't know where any of it is located. I have to try and restore my computer to try again.

Comment: Where are the movies located?

Comment: The cd (change directory) command limits the scope of the find command to the chosen folder.

Comment: The movies are located on my external harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

A quick recursive subroutine will handle this:

```
set theFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder")

tell application "System Events"
    set theFiles to my recursiveSearch(folder theFolder)
    move theFiles to folder theFolder
end tell

on recursiveSearch(theFolder)
    tell application "System Events"
        set theFiles to every file of theFolder whose visible is true
        set theSubFolders to every folder of theFolder
        repeat with thisFolder in theSubFolders
            set theFiles to theFiles & my recursiveSearch(thisFolder)
        end repeat
        return theFiles
    end tell
end recursiveSearch
```

This is easy to modify if you want to accomplish other things (e.g., deleting the empty subfolders, moving only specific kinds of files, etc). Let me know if it needs tweaking.

Comment: The author of the OP was last seen Mar 18 '15 at 21:03, so you'll probably not get a response from them. BTW As coded, if there are any duplicate file names within the target hierarchal folder structure, the duplicates will not be moved. Which of course is a good thing as files wouldn't get overwritten, but potentially not all files get moved.

Comment: Lol - I really should check the date before I post. No worries, it's good code if anyone else is looking.

Answer (score 0):

Folders have an `entire contents` attribute:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to choose folder
    move files of entire contents of f to f
end tell
```

You could also use `find` in the shell:

```
cd ~/Movies/Folder/; find . -type f -exec echo mv '{}' . \;
```

Comment: Thank you, please refer to comment left to adayzdone. I need a little more help.

Comment: You could just replace `move` with `duplicate` (or `mv` with `cp`) and delete the files manually after that. But I don't think that's needed either.

Comment: Did you try the shell script? You could also open a Spotlight window and search for all files in the folder.

Comment: No I haven't used the shell script. I was more familiar with Applescript. And using spotlight I would have to go to each individual folder within the file which I'm trying to avoid because it's over a TB of information.

Comment: An example of how to incorporate a shell script has been appended to my answer.