# Applescript Copy All File from USB to Folder

Tags: applescript

Could you help me to make this script working ?

```
property ignoredVolumes : {"DD APPLE", "MobileBackups"} 
tell application "System Events"

set Destination_Folder to folder "/Users/Joseph/Downloads/Test" of startup disk
set rootVolume to disk item (POSIX file "/Volumes" as text)
set allVolumes to name of every disk item of rootVolume

repeat with aVolume in allVolumes
    if aVolume is not in ignoredVolumes then
        copy every item of folder (aVolume) to Destination_Folder
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

The problem is in the line `copy every item of folder (aVolume) to Destination_Folder` - the error message I get is `Can’t get every file of "NO NAME"`. (No Name is my USB key.)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: The problem is in 
"copy every item of folder (aVolume) to Destination_Folder"
I want to copy all file from aVolume to Destination_Folder

Comment: OK - and what error message or other problem do you encounter ? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: with "copy every item of aVolume to Destination_Folder" I have "Can’t get every file of "NO NAME". (No Name is my USB key)

Comment: OK - I've edited these details into your question now - this should make it more likely that you will get a useful answer.

Comment: See also [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338945/using-applescript-i-want-to-move-every-file-within-the-folder-to-the-root-folder)

Comment: `aVolume` contains the volume name only. You need to store the full path in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Events doesn't have a "copy" command. Where did you get that? You might try "move" instead. Plus "aVolume" is not a folder, it's a disk. You probably want to change "folder aVolume" to "disk aVolume". And you might even need to use "disk (contents of aVolume)"

***EDIT***: Try the following script. I didn't test it but it should work. Good luck.

```
property ignoredVolumes : {"DD APPLE", "MobileBackups", "home", "net"} -- leave home and net in this list
set Destination_Folder to ((path to downloads folder as text) & "Test:") as alias

set mountedVolumes to list disks

repeat with i from 1 to count of mountedVolumes
    set thisVolume to item i of mountedVolumes
    if thisVolume is not in ignoredVolumes then
        tell application "Finder"
            set theItems to items of disk thisVolume
            move theItems to Destination_Folder
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: I do not know a lot about applescript. I Tried:
move every item of disk (contents of aVolume) to Destination_Folder
And
move disk (contents of aVolume) to Destination_Folder 
but it don't work. 
Can’t get folder \"DD APPLE:Users:Joseph:Downloads:Test:\"."
Thank you for your help Regulus6633. If you have another idea..

Comment: I edited my answer with another approach. See the EDIT section. I prefer to use the Finder for moving things rather than System Events. Good luck.

Comment: It perfectly work ! Thank you Regulus. 
I would like to hide the "copy box" during the loading. Do you have some key word in order to focus my research ?